# Powershell - Declaring paths with "$_.pdf" in it

Tags: powershell, variables, path

As title says.

I have several if-statements with "Test-Path" in it so it'd be much better if I just declare the variables right away.

```
$jobs = Get-ChildItem d:\Path\* -recurse -include *.pdf,*.idx |
Select-Object -expand basename |
Sort-Object

$jobs | foreach-object{
     if ((test-path d:\Path\$_.idx) -and (test-path d:\path\$_.pdf)){
        move-item d:\Path\$_.idx d:\Path
        move-item d:\path\$_.pdf d:\Path
        }
      else {
        ....
        }
       }
```

The file name is varying all the time. That's why I'm using "$_.pdf" for example. This is just a simple example. Add even one more file extension to this and yeah. The code functions like "If pdf and idx basenames are true/equal, move them"

This works completely fine, it's just that putting in the paths for each if statement makes it more confusing.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question and show the code for several if statements problem. There might be easier alternatives, but `$_.pdf` makes little sense without more context.

Comment: @vonPryz edited it. im using several test paths and this is just one example. i want to declare them right away. idk if theres an easier way to do this

Comment: @Spottel - have you printed out the value of `$_.pdf` at that point in your code? the `$_` looks like it will be a _fileinfo object_ and you are adding an extension to that. i doubt that will work ... [*grin*]

Comment: Is the idea that you want to move a pair of files? That is `foo.pdf` and `foo.idx` should be moved together to where ever. If `foo.pdf` exists, but not `foo.idx`, then don't move? Add that explanation to the question body too, comments get confusing fast, as sort order is not preserved here.

Comment: @vonPryz The file name is varying all the time. That's why I'm using "$_.pdf" for example. Add even one more file extension to this whole stuff and yeah. The code functions like "If pdf and idx basenames are true/equal, move them"

This works completely fine, it's just that putting in the paths for each if statement makes it more confusing.

Comment: @Spottel - me previous comment is wrong. sorry! [*blush*] you otta have a BaseName in the `$_` at that point ... but you used `-Recurse` and that means your BaseName may not refer to the path that you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

`Test-Path` can take an array of items to be tested. When used so, it will return an array of boolean values. Should that array contain at least one `$false`, there is at least one missing file. If there isn't, all the files are present.

An example is like so,

```
# Create a few test files
set-content foo.idx ''
set-content foo.dpf ''
set-content foo.pub ''

# Instead of foo, you'd populate $s with file's basename
# and use a foreach loop
$s ="foo"

# Test if the trio exists. Note variable $s that contains the basename
if( (Test-Path @(".\$s.idx", ".\$s.dpf", ".\$s.pub")) -contains $false){
  "nay" # Go here if there was at least one false
}else{
  "aye" # go here if all were true
}
# Output
aye
# Change one extension, so trio doesn't exist
if( (Test-Path @(".\$s.idx", ".\$s.dpf", ".\$s.bub")) -contains $false) {
  "nay" # Go here if there was at least one false
}else{
  "aye" # go here if all were true
}
# Output
nay
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, though I do not know the file's base name. There isn't like one pattern. It can totally vary.
It's made for customers, that's why.
It has to grab the item and then "extract" the basename out of it, basically.
That's why I'm using Get-ChildItem

Comment: @Spottel You don't need to know the name. Instead of `$s="foo"`, you'd `foreach($f in gci...) { $s = $_.BaseName ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb.
I just have to put `$path\$_.pdf` there. thats it